# How to change my monitor display from PAL-50 to PAL-60?

Tags: xbox-360, monitor, pal, feeding-frenzy

Recently I decided to dust off one of the first X360 games I played and give them another go for the remaining achievements. One of such games is *Feeding Frenzy*.

After I booted up the game, it threw an error saying it can only run in PAL-60 (Hertz I presume?). So I went into Display Setup on my Xbox, but there is nowhere for me to switch from PAL-50 to PAL-60?

I use a computer monitor for my Xbox. It has both VGA and HDMI inputs. I use the HDMI one.

How do I switch to PAL-60 on my monitor so I can play Feeding Frenzy (or any PAL-60 games) again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a setting on the Xbox itself, no the TV/monitor, however, as seen in [various](http://www.kevblog.co.uk/xbox-360-change-to-pal-60hz/) [places](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6-IEsnhwC5A), the setting isn't accessible on the Xbox when connecting by HDMI.

What you need to do is get your standard Xbox display cable, connect it to a TV and make sure the switch on the cable is set to **TV**, after that the setting to display on PAL 60hz will be available, once you set it you can go back to your HDMI cable.

Comment: I will give it a try. I think I still have the composite cable from when I first purchased the Xbox.